# How do I sample new data for a parametric bootstrap with linear regression?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, parametric

I initially have two data vectors $x$ and $y$, where $y$ is assumed to fit the linear model $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \epsilon$, with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. I fit the model using fitlm in matlab and get estimated values of $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$, and $\sigma$, which I use to calculate the probability $P(x < a|y = b)$ using the cumulative distribution function for $\epsilon$.

After this, I need to use a parametric bootstrap to estimate the upper bound of a confidence interval for this probability, and while I believe I understand the idea behind the bootstrap method, I am a bit lost as to how I generate new datasets for each step in the algorithm in this case.

How I see it is that to generate new estimates for $P$, I need new estimates for $\beta_0$, $\beta_1$ and $\sigma$ to use in the CDF, which means I need to refit the linear model with some new data. This is where I assume I need to sample new data, but I do not understand how. Do I create a new $y$ set using $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is sampled from $N(0,\sigma^2)$, with my initial parameter estimates and fit a new model in each step? Do I update the parameters along the way? I would assume not but when I use my first estimates each time I just get the same value for $P$ every step.

Comment: How do you calculate $P(x < a|y = b)$, given that in a regression model typically there is no assumed distribution for $x$?